# In 2D array (8x8), how do you recursively print sequential numbers from starting location to ending location?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Given a 2D array with the size 8x8. The user inputs a random starting location and a random ending location. In Java, the program must generate sequential numbers (starting at 0 for starting location) up until the ending location. To start, the node up down left or right of the starting location will turn to 1. Then the nodes up down left or right of the 1's will turn to 2's, if they are empty.

I have tried nested loops to generate the numbers and have not been able to cover the entire matrix. I think recursion would work well here, but I am not well versed in writing recursive problems. I have considered initializing entire matrix to 0 at first, then have user input starting location at S and ending location at E. Then inside a while loop, the numbers will generate until end(E) becomes another char/number.

In this scenario, I didn't change End(E) to a number or Start(S) to a number so it was easier to visualize.

```
4    3    2    3    4    5    0    0   
3    2    1    2    3    4    5    0   
2    1    S    1    2    3    4    5   
3    2    1    2    3    4    5    0   
4    3    2    3    4    5    0    0   
5    4    3    4    5    E    0    0   
0    5    4    5    0    0    0    0   
0    0    5    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. Your description sounds like you want a single path from start to end, but the example shows concentric circles. Which is it? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want the concentric circles from start to finish, which will help dictate a path in future. The desired outcome is sequential numbers up until the end location.

Comment: Why not use enhanced for loop?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with nested loops.

The trick is to recognize that you're building concentric diamonds of sequential numbers, e.g. the 3rd step is:

```
      3           yDelta = -3   xDelta =  0
    3   3         yDelta = -2   xDelta = ±1
  3       3       yDelta = -1   xDelta = ±2
3     S     3     yDelta =  0   xDelta = ±3
  3       3       yDelta =  1   xDelta = ±2
    3   3         yDelta =  2   xDelta = ±1
      3           yDelta =  3   xDelta =  0
```

This can be done with a single loop, counting `yDelta` from `-3` to `+3`,
and calculating `xDelta = ±(3 - abs(yDelta))`

*Code*

```java
private static void printDistances(int width, int height, int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd) {
    // Build clear board
    String[][] board = new String[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        Arrays.fill(board[i], ".");

    // Mark start and end locations
    board[yStart][xStart] = "S";
    board[yEnd][xEnd] = "E";

    // Add distances (steps) from start location until end location reached
    int endStep = Math.abs(xEnd - xStart) + Math.abs(yEnd - yStart);
    for (int step = 1; step < endStep; step++) {
        String stepValue = String.valueOf(step);
        for (int dy = -step; dy <= step; dy++) {
            int y = yStart + dy;
            if (y >= 0 && y < height) {
                int dx = step - Math.abs(dy);
                if (xStart - dx >= 0 && xStart - dx < width)
                    board[y][xStart - dx] = stepValue;
                if (dx != 0 && xStart + dx >= 0 && xStart + dx < width)
                    board[y][xStart + dx] = stepValue;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the board
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (x != 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.printf("%2s", board[y][x]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Example 1*

```java
printDistances(8, 8, 2, 2, 5, 5);
```

```
 4  3  2  3  4  5  .  .
 3  2  1  2  3  4  5  .
 2  1  S  1  2  3  4  5
 3  2  1  2  3  4  5  .
 4  3  2  3  4  5  .  .
 5  4  3  4  5  E  .  .
 .  5  4  5  .  .  .  .
 .  .  5  .  .  .  .  .
```

*Example 2*

```java
printDistances(20, 10, 19, 6, 2, 3);
```

```
 .  .  .  .  .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6
 .  .  .  .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5
 .  .  .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4
 .  .  E 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3
 .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
 . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  S
 . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
 .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
 .  .  . 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3
```